# php://input returns data but no further processing is possible

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

The parcel carrier page returns the data in  in json format on the given link.

Sample format:

```
{"event_ts":"2020-09-30 12:56:37 +0200","event":"shipment_confirmed","organization_id":50000,"payload":{"shipment_id":305273,"tracking_number":"500000015524416053236"}}
```

I get data by function:

```
$get_data = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

and everything works fine

I save the data directly to the database and everything is saved correctly (the above example is taken directly from the database)

Then I try to use json_decode on the $get_data variable in same script it returns an empty value.
I tried the script after saving the data to the database to get it from the last added record and further process it, but it doesn't help. Json_decode still returns an empty array.

The moment I put the saved content from the database into a string instead of the file_get_contents("php://input"); the script is processed completely and correctly. Why, when the carrier sends the data, the script is not processed further?

Code snippet:

```
$get_data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO send VALUES ("",?)');
$stmt->bind_param('s',$get_data);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
//saves the data correctly

$get_data = json_decode($get_data); //empty
if ($get_data->event == 'shipment_confirmed'){
//not working
}
```

if i change first line to and run the script myself

```
$get_data = '{"event_ts":"2020-09-30 12:56:37 +0200","event":"shipment_confirmed","organization_id":50000,"payload":{"shipment_id":305273,"tracking_number":"500000015524416053236"}}';
$stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO send VALUES ("",?)');
$stmt->bind_param('s',$get_data);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
//saves the data correctly
    
$get_data = json_decode($get_data);
if ($get_data->event == 'shipment_confirmed'){
//working
}
```

everything works correctly.

Please help.

Comment: What does `json_last_error()` return?

Comment: json_last_error_msg() returning "No error"

Comment: Are you sure you haven't modified `$get_data` before you call `json_decode()`? Try not to reuse variables like you show in your code.

Comment: $get_inpost = (json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true));
$test = $get_inpost['event'];
$get_inpost2 = serialize($get_inpost);
Json_decode must return corectly becouse $get_inpost2 is saving corectly in database (in serialize format), but still $test variable is empty if script is open from the level webhook

Comment: What do you see with `var_dump($get_inpost)`?

Comment: Problem has been solved. It turned out that the php script was working fine. The problem was sending the asynchronous webhook by the package carrier, so next WHERE sql could not be met because the data was out of date. Thanks so much for trying to help!